# Миграции с несколькими DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Классы:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// пользователь который создал документ
    /// </summary>
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Два DbContext'a

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext() : base ("name=ConnectionStringName") { }

    static UserContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UserContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("User");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

class DocumentContext : DbContext
{
    public DocumentContext() : base("name=ConnectionStringName") { }

    static DocumentContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DocumentContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Document");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "User");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

UserContext - хранит данные пользователей (User, Roles, ExternalLogins ...).

DocumentContext -

создаю миграцию для UserContext. В базе создается схема с нужными таблицами

создаю миграцию для DocumentContext, в методе Up EF пытоется создать таблицу которая уже существует, из-за чего я получаю ошибку:

> There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.

```
public partial class InitialDocument : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Document.Documents",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("User.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

            //EF пытается создать таблицу в схеме User,
            //Но она уже создана другой миграцией (UserMigrations)
            //поэтому выходит ошибка - There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.
            //Как объяснить EF чтобы чтобы он не создавал эту таблицу?
        CreateTable(
            "User.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);   
    }
    //скрыто
}
```

**Вопрос** - 
Как объяснить EF чтобы чтобы он не создавал таблицу user?

**Update**

Как временное решение я удаляю кусок кода который создает миграция

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea). Там советуют миграции делать по 1 глобальному контексту, где определена вся схема. А подконтексты не трогать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делать миграции по разным (нескольким) контекстам - не очень удобно, да и не очень хорошо. Насколько мне известно, кроме как руками фиксить данные проблемы, то есть убирать из методов `Up` и `Down` код, который Вам не нужен - не получится.

`EntityFramework` достаточно умен, но решить эту проблему навесив пару атрибутов или через `OnModelCreating` не получится (используя `modelBuilder.Ignore<Entity>()`), хотя, может быть в скором времени `EntityFramework` справится с такой задачей, именно для одной базы данных.

Даже если начинает получаться что-то сделать на подобии того, что Вы хотите - столкнетесь с проблемой, которая приведет к провалу. Если убрать из классов ссылки на другие классы в свойствах - то он не будет подтягивать других таблиц, но тогда не создаст внешних ключей.

Если использовать `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("schema")` а затем при добавлении миграции, указать полное имя Вашего класса конфигурации (полученного из `DbMigrationsConfiguration`) в качестве параметра в `add-migration`, таким образом:

```
add-migration 
    NAME_OF_MIGRATION 
    -ConfigurationTypeName 
    FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_CONFIGURATION_CLASS
```

Тоже Вам не подойдет и вряд ли поможет.

Решение данной коллизии я вижу таким: создать обобщенный контекст и выполнять миграции для одного контекста. Так Вы не потеряете изменений и будет меньше конфликтов. Ссылка из комментария - [Entity Framework: One Database, Multiple DbContexts. Is this a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea) - очень хороший пример.

Если Ваш проект будет не слишком большим и разделение моделей будет минимальным, то этот подход будет прост. Но если у Вас будет много моделей, несколько контекстов, общие классы и наследование - то придется немного напрячься. `EntityFramework` очень *любит* наследование.